# Unable to install the application on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have one application which is used to analyse the logs . When tried installing the EXE file , it gets installed but with the message as-
" Application cannot be installed because the installer has been mis configured . Please contact application author for assistance"

I was later asked to install Adobe AIR to run this application. Once I installed Adobe AIR, this is getting installed but now there is a new error message I am getting error as-
 " This application requires an update to Adobe AIR but downloading that update on your system is not allowed by your administrator. Please contact your administrator".

I see that there is no other administrator on this PC other than me. Am surprised to see this message . Even my colleagues got the first error message but once they installed ADOBE AIR , they are now able to use this analyser on Windows 7, 64 bit.

I uninstalled Adobe AIR and checked but still the same message that  update on your system is not allowed by your administrator. Please contact your administrator as per the second message .

Kindly assist on this and advice.

Thanks in advance,

Guruprasad SP

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the installer and select Properties, go to the compatibility Tab and select the Compatibility mode for the OS that the program was designed for, then tick the run as Admin box, hit OK and try to install it now.

If the program was designed for W7, then all you have to do is right click on the installer and select "run as administrator"

.